# assign struct's address to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Person {
        char *name;
        int age;
        int height;
        int weight;
};
struct Person  Person_create(char *name,int age,int height,int weight)
{
        struct Person who;
        who.name=strdup(name);
        who.age=age;
        who.height=height;
        who.weight=weight;

        return who;
}
void Person_destroy(struct Person who)
{
        free(who.name);
}
void Person_print(struct Person who)
{
        printf("%s %d %d %d %p \n",who.name,who.age,who.height,who.weight,&who);
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        struct Person p1=Person_create("shahrooz",26,180,100);
        Person_print(p1);
        Person_destroy(p1);
        struct Person *p2=&p1;
        printf("%p %p \n",&p1,&p2);
        return 0;
}
```

I assign address of `p1` in a pointer(`p2`).but when printing the address of `p1` and `p2` why the address is not same?

```
printf("%p %p \n",&p1,&p2);
```

returns

```
0x7ffc1b96f980 0x7ffc1b96f978
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: p1 is a different object from p2.  so naturally, the addresses are different.  What would be the same is the contents of p2 and the address of p1

Comment: there is the probability that the code will not work.  This is because the code is trying to pass complete struct objects.  In general only a pointer to a struct should be passed.   Also it will probably fail because the struct being returned by person_create() is on the local stack.  Only intrinsic objects pass properly.  I.E. pointers, int, float, double pass very well but the contents of a struct  don't pass well.

Comment: strongly suggest enabling all the warnings when compiling.  The posted code causes the compiler to output a bunch of warnings.  Please fix the warnings, then re-post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, change

```
printf("%p %p \n",&p1,&p2);
```

to

```
printf("%p %p\n",&p1,p2);
```

because, `&p1` is a *pointer to struct*, so is `p2` (not `&p2`).

FWIW, `&p2` is a *pointer to a pointer to struct*. So,

> *when printing the address of `p1` and `p2` why the address is not same?*

because, the the address of `p1` is no the same as the address of `p2`. The the address of `p1` is the *value* of `p2`.

Comment: Yes i understand it.A pointer has different address but the value of pointer is a address of other thing.Is this true?

Comment: @Shahrooz yeah, that is what pointer is all about, it _points_ to something.